# "orderer" node / docker container exited few seconds after running docker-compose.cli

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyperledger fabric. I used the byfn example and it worked fine and I am now working on my own network. I created crypto-config, config.tx all docker files (including base) as the byfn example.
Every thing works fine untill I run the command "docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d"
all the nodes are generated but the order node fails within a few seconds.

I think the problem could be in my artifacts/genesis.block file, but I could not solve it.

[image]

```
orderer.expleoFabric.com                | 2020-05-21 16:17:59.624 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 003 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
orderer.expleoFabric.com                | 2020-05-21 16:17:59.741 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> PANI 004 Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing configtx manager failed: bad channel ID: 'Orderer-channel' contains illegal characters
orderer.expleoFabric.com                | panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing configtx manager failed: bad channel ID: 'Orderer-channel' contains illegal characters
orderer.expleoFabric.com                |
```

This is from my logs but I could not find Ordrer-channel in any of my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

channel ID can only contain lowercase alphabetical character.
for more information : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/0c3f3f78178f8a639374fba1a12344f381877459/common/configtx/validator.go#L72..L74

Comment: Yes this was just the issue. Thank you